# How to show youtube videos

Tags: ios, xcode, youtube

I was wondering how applications like:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/freedi-player-for-youtube/id471259804?mt=8

stream video to their applications?
Could someone give me some example code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Apple documentation on HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).